# I'm having an issue with checking if a string variable contains only numbers, like string = "1234" ---> meaning that i want it to be true

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: stazionamenti entry box with number input]

[image: stazionamenti entry box with string input]

In my little program i would like to check if stazionamenti_str contains only numbers, my issue is that whatever i type in the input box i always get a False value when checking with .isnumeric(). The result is that when i type a number my program tells me that i typed a string. Thanks in advance!

My code (the important part is at #conversion stazionamenti):

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = Tk()

window.title("Controlla quote")
window.geometry('400x150')

#binari
binari_num=0
def binari(number):
    if number==1:
        binari_num=1
        print("binari= ",binari_num)
    elif number==2:
        binari_num=2
        print("binari= ",binari_num)
    else:
        pass
    return binari_num
#radiobuttons
info = IntVar()
binari_1 = Radiobutton(window, text="1", command=lambda:binari(info.get()),variable=info,value=1).grid(column=1, row=0)
binari_2 = Radiobutton(window, text="2", command=lambda:binari(info.get()),variable=info,value=2).grid(column=2, row=0)
#binari label
binari_scritta=Label(window, text="Binari:").grid(column=0, row=0, stick=W)

#stazionamenti
stazionamenti_str=""
stazionamenti_label=Label(window, text="Stazionamenti: ").grid(column=0, row=1, stick=W)
stazionamenti_entry=Entry(window)
stazionamenti_entry.grid(column=1, row=1, stick=W)

#conversion stazionamenti

def conversion():
    global stazionamenti_num
    global stazionamenti_entry
    if stazionamenti_entry.get():
        if stazionamenti_str.isnumeric() == True:
            stazionamenti_num = int(stazionamenti_entry.get())
            print(stazionamenti_num)
        elif stazionamenti_str.isnumeric() == False:
            print("Errore, stazionamenti non è un numero!")

#avanti
def avanti():
    conversion()
avanti_btn=Button(window, text="Avanti", command=avanti).grid(columnspan=50, stick=E)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Any chance you can reduce your example to an [mre] that does not rely on tkinter?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `stazionamenti_str` is what you are assuming it is inside that function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def conversion():
    global stazionamenti_num
    global stazionamenti_entry
    if stazionamenti_entry.get().isnumeric():
        stazionamenti_num = int(stazionamenti_entry.get())
        print(stazionamenti_num)
    else:
        print("Errore, stazionamenti non è un numero!")
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you described what you changed from the original code. Otherwise we have to examine your code line by line and character by character.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much for the instant help! I will make my questions better next time ;)

Comment: Side-note: While the OP's original code had it, there is no reason for the `global stazionamenti_entry` declaration. `stazionamenti_entry` is never written to in the function, so reading from it implicitly reads from global scope. It's only `stazionamenti_num` that needs the `global` declaration due to being assigned in the function with the intent of modifying the global.

Answer (score -2):

```
def isnum(value):
     try:
         int(value)
     except:
         return false
     return true
```

later on just isnum(your value here) and that will simply return yes or no